# novice: hover/rollover imageswap button using fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, dreamweaver

i have an issue for my site i'm working on [kirandarren.com](http://www.kirandarren.com/) the icons i have on the site I wish to have some kind of image swap or roll over on hover to show that its a button. At first i tried rollover image swap with dreamweaver and it worked great but as soon as i implemented fancybox it seem to clash with the rollover image swap. any ideas?

any assistance in the right direction would be appreciated! I am quite the novice just trying to get our wedding site completed any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks ahead of time! I hope i attached the right code below.

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/our_story_rollover.png','images/directions_rollover.png','images/bridal_party_rollover.png','images/chicago_spots_rollover.png','images/registry_rollover.png')">
```

**Join us on October 13th, 2013 at 5 o'clock in the evening**

**Ceremony will begin at 5:30 |** **Cocktail hour & Reception to follow**

```
<p align="center">

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/58303552"><img src="images/our_story_off.png" name="our_story" width="206" height="210" hspace="14" vspace="0" border="0" id="our_story" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use iframe as it will always conflict with various browsers and might create more issues than solutions.

As you mentioned that you wanted to show that the images are buttons, so just to let the user know this is a link or button, I suggest use onmouseover and onmouseout in the IMG tag. and use a custom jQuery or javascript to give it and animation or transition if you want. eg

```
<script>
function bigImg(x)
{
x.style.height="64px";
x.style.width="64px";
}

function normalImg(x)
{
x.style.height="32px";
x.style.width="32px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">

<p>The function bigImg() is triggered when the user moves the mouse pointer over the image.</p>
<p>The function normalImg() is triggered when the mouse pointer is moved out of the image.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

HINT: to create a better looking button, USE box-shadow (css property in the script you will create).

Comment: the issue is i've designed a specific graphic png for each icon that has rounded corners and i heard it was very challenging to make box-shadows when the image itself wants to be rounded corners even though it sits inside of a rectangular frame. also iframe was the best and easiest way to navigate the site "on one page" i'm not sure what else to use to have it load without clicking to another page

Comment: use div and mark the divs in a static positioning, once your feel they are proper, use jquery and use HIDE() and SHOW() functions to hide and show your divs, use them with OnMouseClick() event for the div. THIS will be an iFrame created by you yourself and you dont have to goto a new page

Comment: for jquery refer w3schools.com